# How do you parse a JSON array with TouchJSON?

Tags: json, ios4, touchjson

I'm using TouchJSON. Made a call to my Rails app to fetch all "posts" at localhost:3000/posts.json.  This returns a JSON array, surrounded by square brackets. I'm currently set up to convert the jsonString into an NSDictionary, but that fails due to the square brackets.

```
NSString *jsonString=[self jsonFromURLString:@"http://localhost:3000/posts.json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error];
```

What's the best way to turn this result into an NSArray using the TouchJSON library?

```
Error Domain=kJSONScannerErrorDomain Code=-101 "Could not scan dictionary. Dictionary that does not start with '{' character."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use the `-deserialize:` method and then figure out what kind of object you have after its done?

Or to answer your specific question, use `-deserializeAsArray:`

Comment: The -deserializeAsArray: function is deprecated I guess because it's not available anymore in the TouchJSON code. But as JeremyP already stated just use the -deserialize: function and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I think most parsers frown with array data. You'll have to return a hash:

```
{'result': [Your array data]}
```